# jquery Modal Dialogue. On close refresh page with specific parameters

Tags: jquery-ui, parameter-passing

I was wondering if there is someway to change the url of a reload when I close the modal window...

Right now I have this in the onClose event...

```
      , close: function (event, ui) {
        //debugger;
       //if($url.contains)
       location.reload(true);
    }
```

ideally I would like to be able to pass a couple of parameters to the location.reload(true) function.
Or maybe there is another way to reload?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your location.href directly and it will load corresponding page. such as:

`location.href = location.href + '?a=1'`